# How to upload XML file from web server to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, xml, webserver

I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.3 and got 2 Tables included. My task here is to upload XML file from a web server to my Table. One of them looks like this:

```
-<candidates>
<publicationDate>2016-04-26 15:00:00</publicationDate>
-<candidate>
<name>John</name>
<party>Party1</party>
</candidate>
-<candidate>
<name>Tom</name>
<party>Party2</party>
</candidate>
</candidates>
.....
```

and goes like this with 13 records.At the very beginning I got a notification that given XML file consists no information about styles included. Also, the other information says  that default format of returning data is JSON, so to get XML in the header `Accept` must be included with value `application/xml`.

It's my very beginning with MySQL and I will be very thankful for any advises.

Comment: do you want to upload it directly to mysql or your are using php ?

Comment: Directly to MySql, because i need it after that in my c# project.